# Third party OAuth inside Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am developing a Chrome App which requires the user to authenticate against a third party website for OAuth (for e.g Twitter).

I want to be able to

- Open the OAuth URL from the Chrome app.
- Detect if the user has authorized and got redirect to my "redirect" URL (detect the tab is closed?)
- Fetch the access token from the redirected URL in the Chrome app.

I am unable to think of a way to do this? Can someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chrome.browser.openTab with callback URL localhost, where you run a local webserver, I could see being an option.

But I think the simplest and recommended solution would be to use chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow. Here is an example with facebook oauth flow [on Github](https://github.com/blackgirl/Facebook_Oauth2_sample_for_extensions)